# How to Import parent service dynamically?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, performance

I am injecting service-A (85KB) in service-B (15KB) and service-B in app.comp.ts. Is possible to import the service-A dynamically in service-B or Service-B import dynamically in app.comp.ts when required.

Stackblitz Demo [Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-v4-angular-modal-fy4ccj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

FlowChart [Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yXXA.png)

Comment: Does [this](https://dev.to/anduser96/angular-dynamically-configure-an-injector-for-dynamic-views-1lb4) help?

Comment: What you mean import dynamically? Have you looked into interfaces? Here's an article for it: https://medium.com/hackernoon/creating-interfaces-for-angular-services-1bb41fbbe47c

Comment: it is really hard to make it integrated with angular DI. it it required ? could you descrbe, what are these services used for, so we could advice how to handle that?

Comment: @Andrei these are custom services. I am already working on code refactoring to decrease the initial app size but if lazy loading these services is possible? it will make my work a lot easier..

Comment: it depends... main question is: do your services inject anything in their constructor? ""

Comment: @Andrei yes, it injecting another custom service and I want that this injected service should be injected lazy lazily

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-v4-angular-modal-fy4ccj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: ok, i ll try to provide the answer, considering how little information we have

Comment: @Andrei How to use it without async-await? I am using that service in many components and using async and await  creates a new problem 

Snippet: https://ibb.co/K0MpWK6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can make use of angular DI here. but you shouldn't import your services directly:

```
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private injector: Injector) {}
  
  async loadService() {
    const {DeviceService} = await import('./temp.service');
    const service = this.injector.get(DeviceService);
    service.doSomething();
  }
}
```

why it works: DeviceService provides itself to global injector because of `provideIn: 'root'`. and because of that we can  download the service and then instantiate it from injector

Comment: How to use it without async-await? I am using that service in many components and using async and await creates a new problem Snippet: https://ibb.co/K0MpWK6

Comment: you just can't. if you've put it to lazy loaded module - you probably not having it yet